# How do I pause JavaScript execution within the AVD Emulator running in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

There's a generated element I want to inspect using the Chrome inspector, but the fn+f8 shortcut does not pause the page (my guess is because it's wrapped in the emulator, chrome cannot pause it.)

macOs Catalina
Ionic+Cordova+Angular Project running in an Android 27 Image on Android Studio.

Is there a way to **Freeze** the current JS Execution as is, so that I can inspect the generated HTML+Css?
Throttling the network speed doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: use `debugger` keyword in your js stop execution. but for the debugger to apply you should have chrome inspector open and device connected to your chrome.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thank you, I will try that.

I can set breakpoints and step through, but I specifically want to avoid that.

I'm looking for a way to test/QA, and then when I need to, freeze the DOM, instead of having to re-compile to stop at 1-N pre-programmed spots.

Comment: you dont need to recompile. just use chrome inspecter and click on the line to set breakpoint.

Comment: Hmm, I have to read up/work through how the debugger works properly - I set breakpoints but it was stepping way too deep - into dependency sources instead of where I needed the breakpoint.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: are you building debug apk or production apk??

Comment: I can run either one, neither gives me a 'pause' option, except for the debugger 'breakpoints'